# android save sql query result as cursor exception

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have a little issue with that piece of code :

```
public static int localUserIdByServerUserId(int serverUserId, String serverName){

        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, "opalqnka_sys_tpl.sqlite", null, 1);
        dbHelper.getDatabase();
        dbHelper.executeQuery("users", "objectId", "2");
        dbHelper.executeQuery("users","serverName","opalqnka");
        dbHelper.executeQuery("users", "objectId", "3");
        dbHelper.executeQuery("users","serverName","opalqnka");
        dbHelper.executeQuery("users", "objectId", "3");

        String query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE objectId = "+serverUserId+" AND serverName = '"+serverName+"' LIMIT 1";
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        cursor = dbHelper.executeSQLQuery(query);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
             cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        int uuid = Integer.parseInt(result.get(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"))));
        Log.w("localUSerByIdServerUserId","LocalUserByIdServerUserId result : "+uuid);
        cursor.close();
        return uuid;
    }
```

It's throwing me an `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0`   at this line :

```
int uuid = Integer.parseInt(result.get(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"))));
```

I'm not really familiar with database that's why I'm asking maybe stupid questions here.
So if anybody has a solution for my problem, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    Log.i("result ","Result : "+result.toString());
    Log.i("CURSOR ","Cursor Position : "+cursor.getPosition());
    Integer uuid = Integer.parseInt(result.get(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
```

Answer (score 2):

First clear what you want.
The crashing issue occur coz of not getting any value in result.
first you check the record add in result. Print log like this

```
Log.e("",""+result.toString());
```

If there is only one record the you can get like this:

```
int uuid = Integer.parseInt(result.get(0));
```

If there is more than one record the you can use for loop and get more than one ids:

```
for(int i=0; i<result.size();i++)
    int uuid = Integer.parseInt(result.get(i));
```